# Is there any way to define flags for cabal dependencies?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I recently ran into a Cabal issue that I only managed to solve by manually installing [`transformers-compat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-compat)  with the `-f transformers3` flag in my cabal sandbox before running `cabal install` for my project.

Is there any way to indicate in my application's `.cabal` file that I depend on a library so that it is built with the specific build flag?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like transformers-compat is supposed to be a shim used for old projects with old dependencies. Can you update your package to depend on the newer version of transformers?

Comment: Aside: calling any kind of technical problem with Cabal "Cabal hell" is not very informative. It'd be easier to help you if you described which error message you were getting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **cannot** do this with Cabal.

One way to do this is to use [Stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README.html). Edit your `stack.yaml` to include

```
flags:
  transformers-compat:
    transformers3: true
```

See also the section on [flags](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration.html#flags).

Comment: Hi, is the first sentence here this still valid? Apparently cabal got the same functionality quite recently.

Answer (score 18):

Newer versions of Cabal let you specify [constraints](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build.html#cfg-field-constraints) in your `cabal.project.local` or `cabal.project` file. For example:

```
constraints: hmatrix +openblas
```

> Is there any way to indicate in my application's .cabal file that I depend on a library so that it is built with the specific build flag?

No, but in your case this is not actually a problem in the solver and is rather and uninformative error (caused by someone's less than judicious uses of flags).

Comment: The original link doesn't seem to work but got me close enough to find: https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-constraints

Answer (score 17):

Looks like it's not possible to specify such a dependency via the `build-depends` field in your `.cabal` file. [`buildDepends` is defined as `[Dependency]`](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/PackageDescription.hs#L781), where `data Dependency = Dependency PackageName VersionRange`. You can use `cabal install --constraint="transformers-compat +transformers3"`, though.

Looking at the `transformers-compat.cabal` file, I think that the solver should be able to figure out the correct flag assignment if you constrain your dependency on `transformers` appropriately. E.g. `build-depends: transformers >= 0.3 && < 0.4` should force the solver to choose `transformers-compat +transformers3`. If this doesn't work, it may be a bug in the solver.

Answer (score 11):

I also struggled for a long time to find a solution to this problem. I just found one! You have to modify the global cabal configuration file at `~/.cabal/config`. Add a [constraints](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build.html#cfg-field-constraints) line like this to the initial section of the file:

> constraints: hmatrix +openblas

This enables the `openblas` flag for the `hmatrix` package. It will be used automatically the next time the package is installed. If there is a way to set such a flag locally for a sandbox, I could not find it.

Answer (score 6):

`cabal` now supports an elegant way to do this similar to `stack`, [through `cabal.project` configuration options](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-project.html#package-configuration-options).

```
package transformers-compat
    flags: +transformers3
```

will *add* the flag `transformers3` when building the package `transformers-compat`.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of ways to constrain the version for installation.

1. Add lower and upper bounds to package versions in the cabal file like [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242169/mikhail-glushenkov) mentioned above, [example of such a file here](https://github.com/Soostone/hadron/blob/master/hadron.cabal)
2. Additionally, you can override the settings in the .cabal file with the flag `cabal install --constraint="bar-2.1"`

To remove a specific version of a package:

- In a sandbox you can unregister a version with `cabal sandbox hc-pkg unregister bar-2.1`
- Global unregistering can be done with this command outside of sandbox `ghc-pkg unregister bar-2.1`