# Is it possible to use cpp preprocessors with haskell stack

Tags: haskell, build, c-preprocessor, haskell-stack

Is it possible to use cpp preprocessors with haskell stack,

e.g:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module MyModule (
  main
  #ifdef TEST
    ,functionUnderTest
    ,functionAlsoUnderTest
  #endif
  ) where ....
```

with cabal, the following settings in .cabal appear to work:
`cpp-options:         -DTEST` 
is it possible to reproduce this with stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/yaml_configuration.md#flags), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123917/630160) answer here on SO and also this [github issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/191)

> ## flags
>
> Flags can be set for each package separately, e.g.
>
> ```
> flags:   package-name:
>     flag-name: true
> ```
>
> Flags will only affect packages in your packages and extra-deps settings. Packages that come from the snapshot global
>   database are not affected.

Alternatively you can pass a flag on directly when invoking stack with `--flag`, I assume the syntax would be something like

```
stack test --flag project:TEST
```